# Error while loading JSON data into HIVE table

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I have a JSON data which I have to load in HIVE TABLE. While creating an external table to load the JSON, I am getting multiple parse exceptions because of usage of array and nested struct which is not getting placed properly.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "uploadTimeStamp" : "1486631318873",
  "PDID" : "01",
  "data" : [ {
    "Data" : {
      "unit" : "rpm",
      "value" : "0"
    },
    "EventID" : "Event1",
    "PDID" : "01",
    "Timestamp" : 1486631318873,
    "Timezone" : 330,
    "Version" : "1.0",
    "pii" : { }
  }, {
    "Data" : {
      "heading" : "N",
      "Location" : "false",
      "latitude" : "14.022425",
      "longitude" : "78.760587",
      "Location2" : "false",
      "speed" : "10"
    },
    "EventID" : "Event2",
    "PDID" : "01",
    "Timestamp" : 1486631318873,
    "Timezone" : 330,
    "Version" : "1.1",
    "pii" : { }
  }, {
    "Data" : {
      "x" : "1.1",
      "y" : "1.2",
      "z" : "2.2"
    },
    "EventID" : "Event3",
    "PDID" : "01",
    "Timestamp" : 1486631318873,
    "Timezone" : 330,
    "Version" : "1.0",
    "pii" : { }
  }, {
    "EventID" : "Event4",
    "Data" : {
      "value" : "50",
      "unit" : "percentage"
    },
    "Version" : "1.0",
    "Timestamp" : 1486631318873,
    "PDID" : "01",
    "Timezone" : 330
  }, {
    "Data" : {
      "unit" : "kmph",
      "value" : "70"
    },
    "EventID" : "Event5",
    "PDID" : "01",
    "Timestamp" : 1486631318873,
    "Timezone" : 330,
    "Version" : "1.0",
    "pii" : { }
  } ]
}
```

And here is one of the parse exceptions:

```
NoViableAltException(313@[])
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.type(HiveParser.java:42781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.colType(HiveParser.java:42538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameType(HiveParser.java:42058)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeOrPKOrFK(HiveParser.java:42308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeOrPKOrFKList(HiveParser.java:37966)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:5259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2763)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1756)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1178)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:204)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1384)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1161)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:776)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 13:23 missing > at ',' near 'struct' in column type
line 14:6 cannot recognize input near '<' 'Data' ':' in column type
```

It looks like closing the nested struct or multiple structs within one array is not going through.

What could be the point of correction here?

Create table stmt:

```
create table table_prd_in_general_events_test7(
uploadtime bigint,
pdid string,
data array<
struct<Data:struct<
unit:string,
value:int>,
eventid:string,
pdid:bigint,
time:bigint,
timezone:int,
version:int,
pii:struct<pii:string>>,
struct<Data:struct<
heading:string,
Location:string,
latitude:bigint,
longitude:bigint,
Location2:string,
speed:int>,
eventid:string,
pdid:bigint,
time:bigint,
timezone:int,
version:int,
pii:struct<pii:string>>,
struct<Data:struct<
unit:string,
value:int>,
eventid:string,
pdid:bigint,
time:bigint,
timezone:int,
version:int,
pii:struct<pii:string>>,
struct<Data:struct<
x:int,
y:int,
z:int>,
eventid:string,
pdid:bigint,
time:bigint,
timezone:int,
version:int,
pii:struct<pii:string>>,
struct<Data:struct<
heading:string,
isLastKnownLocation:string,
latitude:bigint,
longitude:bigint,
noLastKnownLocation:string,
speed:int>,
eventid:string,
pdid:bigint,
time:bigint,
timezone:int,
version:int,
pii:struct<pii:string>>
>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
'/xyz/abc/';
```

Add jar:

```
ADD JAR /home/hive/lib/hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.0.jar;
```

Comment: Update the post with the create table statement you used..

Comment: I think it would make sense to also provide the command/statement you are using to import this json file and the SerDe you are using.

Comment: Here is the create table stmt:

Comment: updated the question

Comment: `cannot recognize input near '<' 'Data' ':'`... Check your `<>` symbols again

Comment: Looks like the error is because of multi line feature of my json. I tried creating the table but while selecting the data from table, it gives error in the first line itself pointing towards ByteArrayException.

Comment: Is there a way to load multiline json data into hive tables ??

Comment: This is the exact exception while loading multiple line JSON in hive:                 Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@8b89b3a; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@8b89b3a; line: 1, column: 3]